# Not able to change background color of a screen in kivy

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to change the color of background of whole screen of my multiple screen app but in this screen the backgroung appears to be o the side of whitish blue , like being white having little blue or grey texture in it, can you suggest me how i ca make my screen backgound white
""":

```
name: "loginip"
email: "email"
password: "password"
MDFloatLayout:
    canvas:
        Color:   
            rgba: 1,1,1,1
    MDFloatLayout:
        canvas:
            Color:   
                rgba: 1,1,1,1
        MDIconButton :
            icon : "arrow-left"
            pos_hint : {"center_y":.95}
            user_font_size :"30sp"
            theme_text_color : "Custom"
            text_color : rgba(26,24,58,255)
            on_release :
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
                root.manager.current = "hello"
        MDLabel :
            text : "W e l c o m e   !"
            font_style : "H1"
            bold : True
            font_size : "26sp"
            pos_hint : {"center_x":.6,"center_y": .85}
            #halign : "center"
            color : rgba(0,0,59,255)
        MDLabel :
            text : "Sign in to continue"
            font_style : "H2"
            #bold : True
            font_size : "18sp"
            #size_hint_x : .85
            pos_hint : {"center_x": .6,"center_y": .79}
            #halign : "center"
            color : rgba(135,133,193,255)
        MDFloatLayout:
            size_hint : .7,.07
            pos_hint : {"center_x" : .5 , "center_y":.63}
            mg_bg_color : rgba(255,255,255,255)
            TextInput:
                id : email
                hint_text : "Email"
                font_style: "H1"
                size_hint_y : .75
                pos_hint : {"center_x" : .43, "center_y" : .5}
                background_color : 1,1,1,0
                foreground_color : rgba(0,0,59,255)
                cursor_color : rgba(0,0,59,255)
                font_size : "14sp"
                cursor_width: "2sp"
                multiline : False
            MDFloatLayout:
                pos_hint : {"center_x" : .45,"center_y" : 0}
                size_hint_y : .03
                md_bg_color : rgba(178,178,178,255)
```

"""

Comment: You need to add `VertexInstruction` objects like `Rectangle`, `Ellipse` etc. to the canvas along with color.

Comment: Thankyou so much ApuCoder for your time , it solved the problem.